# Where does systemd get the build time in order to advance?

Tags: linux, systemd, clock

On bootup, systemd gives me

> System time before build time, advancing clock

if the hardware clock is older than the build time.

But where does it get this build time? It advances the time to 09/Sept/2020

But `uname -v` gives me 15/Feb/2021

and `/etc/timestamp` contains 21/July/2021.

So where does systemd get this build time from?

Answer (score 2):

That timestamp probably comes from the build-time of the systemd daemon, and not the build time of the kernel (uname). I don't know where /etc/timestamp comes from.

After looking at [systemd code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd), I think the build-time is set when the systemd binaries are compiled, or if present, from the file /usr/lib/clock-epoch

This is the error message:

```
$ ag 'System time before build time'

src/core/main.c
1602:                log_info("System time before build time, advancing clock.");
```

The condition for that error message depends on the output of the function...

```
$ ag clock_apply_epoch

src/shared/clock-util.c
142:int clock_apply_epoch(ClockChangeDirection *ret_attempted_change) {
```

...which will stat a hard-coded path or use a constant defined at compile time.

```
$ ag EPOCH_FILE

src/shared/clock-util.c
140:#define EPOCH_FILE "/usr/lib/clock-epoch"
152:        if (stat(EPOCH_FILE, &st) < 0) {
154:                        log_warning_errno(errno, "Cannot stat " EPOCH_FILE ": %m");
```

The constant is defined here:

```
$ ag TIME_EPOCH
meson.build
724:conf.set('TIME_EPOCH', time_epoch)
```

Comment: Thanks but `/usr/lib/clock-epoch` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: That's why there is a condition for that state in the code. Also, it's really easy to check if the file is there, so I'm not sure why it seems that way for you. On this system, that file definitely does not exist.